# Adding class to images and videos with Summernote widget in Django 2

Tags: css, django, class, widget, summernote

I'm looking for a way to add a class, which I could modify in css, to images and videos in both editor forms and html templates displaying the form. I'm using the SummernoteInplaceWidget() from django-summernote package and it's working fine except this feature.
I use bootstrap 4 with it.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteInplaceWidget
from .models import Post


class PostFormModel(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'image', ]
        widgets = {
            'content': SummernoteInplaceWidget(attrs={'class': 'summer-img-class'}),
        }
```

post_form.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block mt %} mt-2 {% endblock mt %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Blog Post</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
                {% if form.image.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ form.image.errors }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        {% block jquery %}
            {{ form.media }}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

post_detail.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block mt %} mt-2 {% endblock mt %}
{% block content %}

  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="shadow-sm rounded row media-body">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3 align-self-center">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img align-middle mx-auto d-none d-sm-block " src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img-sm align-midle mx-auto d-block d-sm-none " src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}"">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-9">
          <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            {% if object.author == user %}
              <div>
                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>
        </div>
    <div class="row media-body pt-3">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        {% if post.image %}

          <a href="{{ object.image.url  }}"><img alt="" src="{{ object.image.large.url }}" class="post_image rounded mx-auto mb-2 d-block"/></a>

        {% endif %}
         <p class="article-content ml-3">{{ object.content|safe }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </article>

{% endblock content %}
```

I tried to add some styling to `.article-content`, it didn't have any effect, the same for this class in css (I imagine it can be more effectively):

```
.summer-img-class * {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Maybe it should be done with Jquery somehow, I don't know.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific, maybe showing us the code using the widget. Normally, form widgets accept the `attrs` parameter in their initialiser, taking a dictionary of HTML attributes, e.g. `SummernoteInplaceWidget(attrs={'class': 'custom-class'})` will add the class `custom-class` to the HTML tag wrapping the widget.

Comment: Thanks, added attribute to widget to reflect the effort.

Comment: Not clear what the issue is now. If you look at the source of the page in your browser, is the class `summer-img-class` not added? If it is, then your original question is answered. The fact that the CSS doesn't have any effect means you have a different question, but then you need to ask that question specifically (and that's just a css/html question I guess) and let us know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes dirkgroten, you are right, initially I thought that maybe there is a specific configuration of the plugin (like custom setting in settings.py) however the title of my query suggest just what you pointed out, which wasn't very clear. I managed to achieve what I wanted with pure css, just added !important to each points and changed the div which the class pertains to. Thanks for your help anyway!